# How do I get rid of xpack 401 error in Kibana OSS version for MAC

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I have an Amazon ES with 6.7.0. Recently migrated from 6.2.3 --> 6.7.0.
I have a separate Kibana instance talking to Amazon ES. I am trying to locally setup a kibana to connect to AmazonES (through aws-es-proxy).

I see this error:

```
log [01:48:52.120] [warning][license][xpack] License information from the X-Pack plugin could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster. Authentication Exception :: {"path":"/_xpack","statusCode":401,"response":"{\"Message\":\"Your request: '/_xpack' is not allowed.\"}"}
```

And I am using kibana-oss-6.7.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz which shouldn't have x-pack

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with heartbeat-oss, have you found a solution?

Comment: AWS flavor of Elastic search doesn't have x-pack. AWS' ES is the community edition.